# Small jQuery script working in Chrome, not in firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small script on my e-commerce site checkout page. It is simply moving a div to another location on the page, as the HTML code of the checkout page is locked.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#div_articleContainer_116").insertAfter("#table_checkout_cart0");
});
</script>
```

This bit of code successfully moves the div in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is not functioning. You can see this in action at: https://www.yandasmusic.com/one-page-checkout.asp

Any tips? I'm very much a jquery novice. Thanks!

Comment: can you reproduce this problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: jQuery is cross-browser, so your issue is elsewhere

Comment: Here's a fiddle of something similar. This fiddle is working in all browsers. You are most likely right that the issue is elsewhere, I just have no idea where to look. http://jsfiddle.net/2fj1fxd1/

Comment: There is no element with id `div_articleContainer_116` in the page you point to, nor is there a element with `table_checkout_cart0`

Comment: Holy smokes your right. It looks like that containing div is conditional to either the items in the cart, or the browser.

Comment: Thanks for making me notice this @PatrickEvans . I changed the code to target a div that I know would always be preset. It seems it is working now.